# Using "let" to assign a tuple to a value in sml

Tags: tuples, sml, let

Im trying to write a function that does the following, takes in :

```
[ #"t" ,#"h" ,#"e" ,#" " ,#"c" ,#"a" ,#"t" ]
```

The following is the output:

```
( [#"t" ,#"h" ,#"e" ] , [#" " ,#"c" ,#"a" ,#"t" ] )
```

so far I have..

```
fun isLetter c =  #"a" <= c andalso c <= #"z";
//(this works fine and is used within the main function wordPop)

fun wordPop [] = ([],[])
  | wordPop (hd::tl) = if not (isLetter hd)
                       then ([], hd::tl)
                       else (* ...not too sure... (1) *)
```

I know that I have to do something that looks like this at (1)

```
let (wordPop tl) in (x,y) end;
```

and somehow add hd to x. But not 100% sure how to do this.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to split a list into a pair of halves, in which case the fact that it is a list of characters isn't relevant. Perhaps you can explain what you are trying to do more clearly.

Comment: Okay,  I'm given a phrase, this phrase is in the form of the input shown above. I have to split this input into a tuple, where the first in the pair is the first word in the phrase, and the second in the pair is the rest of the phrase. I'm not sure if that's clear enough, sorry I'm not that good with words.

Comment: so as you can see I'm checking to see if the first value in the list is a letter or not (if it's not then it's a space in which case its the end of the first word) if it is then I need to be able to step though the function making new tuples as I go with the most up to date phrase. then, after it reaches a non letter character it should return the tuple.

Comment: So you want to split on the first non letter, keeping that first non-letter as part of the second half. Note that your `isLetter` is too verbose: just use `fun isLetter c = #"a" <= c andalso c <= #"z"`;

Comment: I want to split on the first non letter, having the word on the left half and the rest of the phrase on the right i.e.(some psudocode where | denotes the seperation between the left tuple value and the right tuple value)    hello this is an example => hello| this is an example

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about the isLetter function so far though. I felt it was a little off... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like homework, so here is a hint:

In the non-basis case `(hd::tl)`, if `isLetter hd` is *false* then you are ready to directly return something (no need for a recursive function call). Think carefully about what you want to return if the input looks like just `explode(" cat")` (i.e. `[#" ", "c", "a", "t"]` -- note the space).

As far as the other case (`isLetter hd` evaluating to true) goes, suppose you are processing the characters in "he cat". Then `hd = #"h"` and `tl = [#"e", #" ", "c", "a", "t"]`.
If in this context you execute

```
let val (x,y) = wordPop tl
```

then `x = [#"e"]` and `y = [#" ", "c", "a", "t"]`.

Given such `x` and `y` -- where do you want to place `hd = #"h"` before returning?

Comment: Uhm, I would say return (hd::x, y).

Comment: so it would be fun wordPop [] = ([],[]) | wordPop (hd::tl) if( not (isLetter hd)) then ([], tl) else let val (hd::x,y) = wordPop tl; .... I get the feeling I'm not getting this at all.

Comment: @James Almost there. 1) You need `=` before `if` and the part after `else` should begin `let val (x,y) = wordPop tl in ... end;`

Comment: Thank you so much, Finally got there in the end. :)!

Answer (score 1):

The final solution I got:

```
fun isLetter c =  #"a" <= c andalso c <= #"z";

fun wordPop [] = ([],[]) |
    wordPop (hd::tl) = if(not (isLetter hd))
                          then ([],(hd::tl))
                          else let val (x,y) = wordPop tl in (hd::x,y) end;
```